# Create new model array in List<T> containing values in every four indexes

Tags: c#, list, linq, foreach, asp.net-mvc-5

I need to add a new array containing model values to a list that uses values present in groupings of four indexes.

I am using the code below to retrieve the values from the corresponding database table:

```
public List<Log> ViewItFilterUseCount()
{
    var ndtms2Utils = new NDTMS2UtilsEntities();

    var valueQuery = (from log in ndtms2Utils.Logs
        where log.Message.Contains("ViewIt - View Data")
        select log);

    List<Log> logList = new List<Log>();

    foreach (var value in valueQuery)
    {
        Log model = new Log();
        model.Id = value.Id;
        model.Date = value.Date;
        model.Thread = value.Thread;
        model.Level = value.Level;
        model.Logger = value.Logger;
        model.Message = value.Message;
        model.Exception = value.Exception;
        logList.Add(model);
    }

    return logList;
}
```

I need to extract values from the Message variable that appear after a : symbol and use them to create a new value for the Message field in the following format:  ViewIt - View Data - the user has selected: messageValue1, messageValue2, messageValue3, messageValue4.

The value for the remaining variables in the model can be filled using those present in the the last index of the group of 4.

The data when in table format looks like this:

[image]

The Message added using the first four rows as an example would read:

ViewIt - View Data - the user has selected: Clients in treatment, Opiate, East of England, Essex.

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: The fastest way to explain the problem is to show your attempt.

Comment: All depends on your input message and the format it's coming in. You could for example do it with these two lines 'string arr = model.Message.Split(':')[1].Split(',');'
 and... 'model.Message = " ViewIt - View Data - the user has selected:" + arr[0] + "," + arr[1] + "," + arr[2] + "," + arr[3]'

Comment: Obviously the above completely fails if there is no colon/ multiple colons and is guessing your message values are split by a comma, but hopefully it's a start.

Comment: Please post a snippet of what 'valueQuery' returns, ie the string you are trying to manipulate.

Comment: It's not clear what `value.Message` looks like, nor how you want to "crate a new value" from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working by converting the output from the database to an Array and then using Rhaokiels Array code to perform the processing as shown below:

```
public List<Log> ViewItFilterUseCount()
        {
            var ndtms2Utils = new NDTMS2UtilsEntities();

            var logQuery = (from logs in ndtms2Utils.Logs
                where logs.Message.Contains("ViewIt - View Data")
                select logs).ToArray();

            int index = 0;
            return (from log in logQuery
                where log.Message.StartsWith("ViewIt - View Data")
                group log by (index++ / 4) into grp
                let log = grp.Last()
                select new Log
                {
                    Id = log.Id,
                    Date = log.Date,
                    Thread = log.Thread,
                    Level = log.Level,
                    Logger = log.Logger,
                    Message = "ViewIt - View Data - the user has selected: " + string.Join(", ", grp.Select((l) => l.Message.Substring(l.Message.IndexOf(": ") + 2))),
                    Exception = log.Exception
                }).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: You don't need the double `where` clause. Because you already know that all the members of `logQuery` will conform. Although I would use `StartsWith` over `Contains` to reduce the possibility of false positives.

Answer (score 0):

This will group the log entries purely 4 at a time and give a combined message as output:

```
public List<Log> ViewItFilterUseCount()
{
    var ndtms2Utils = new NDTMS2UtilsEntities();

    // Query LINQ-to-Entities database for all matching rows
    var valueQuery = ndtms2Utils.Logs.Where((o) => o.Message.StartsWith("ViewIt - View Data")).ToList();

    // Then process client-side
    int index = 0;
    return (from log in valueQuery
            group log by (index++ / 4) into grp
            let log = grp.Last()
            select new Log {
                Id = log.Id,
                Date = log.Date,
                Thread = log.Thread,
                Level = log.Level,
                Logger = log.Logger,
                Message = "ViewIt - View Data - the user has selected: " + string.Join(", ", grp.Select((l) => l.Message.Substring(l.Message.IndexOf(": ") + 2))),
                Exception = log.Exception
            }).ToList();
}
```

**This can fail if the order of incoming log entries gets changed slightly, or an entry is missing will cause remaining entries to shift.**

Comment: the increment on the index is throwing an error: An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator is there anyway around this I have tried putting into the select which also throws an error

Comment: have also tried replacing the index++ with the Id value when running the linq I'm getting the error:  'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'NDTMS2.Models.Log Last[Log](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[NDTMS2.Models.Log])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. I am using MVC 5 by the way

Comment: My code works exactly as written in .NET v4.0.30319, perhaps you have modified something in a way that changes how it works? https://i.imgur.com/B67ZNjc.png

Comment: no changes this is what I am getting https://imgur.com/a/Vll80oj, I am getting the values from a database table

Comment: Oh, I see the problem is the LINQ code is being executed server side in your code, vs client side in mine.

Comment: Alright, I've modified those two pieces so that LINQ to Entities should know how to translate them. I would advise against using the Id value already associated with each line for grouping because your screenshot shows that they don't land on even increments of 4. Also I have no way to test the code as LINQ to Entities, so you'll have to let me know if it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194883/discussion-between-cryofusion87-and-rhaokiel).

Answer (score 0):

as i understood you try to bind parsed string into model object.
this example you can run in Linqpad (i hope it will help)

```
void Main()
{

    List<string> l = new List<string>()
    {
        "ViewIt - View Data - selected Key is: client1",
        "ViewIt - View Data - selected Substance is: vodka",
        "ViewIt - View Data - selected Region is: Russia",
        "ViewIt - View Data - selected Area is: Moscow",

        "ViewIt - View Data - selected Key is: client2",
        "ViewIt - View Data - selected Substance is: Essex",
        "ViewIt - View Data - selected Region is: England",
        "ViewIt - View Data - selected Area is: Essex",

        "ViewIt - View Data - selected Key is: client3",
        "ViewIt - View Data - selected Substance is: IceTea",
        "ViewIt - View Data - selected Region is: US",
        "ViewIt - View Data - selected Area is: New York"
    };
    List<DATA> datalist = new List<UserQuery.DATA>();
    l.Where(w=> w.Contains("View Data")).Select((v, i) => new { Index = i, Value = v })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 4)
        .ToList().ForEach(r => {
                datalist.Add(parseStrings(r.Select(v=>v.Value).ToList()));
        });

    Console.Write(datalist);
}


public DATA parseStrings(List<string> list){

    DATA d = new DATA();

    list.ForEach(f => {
        var row = f.Substring(f.IndexOf("selected") + 9)
        .Split(':');

        switch (row[0].TrimEnd(" is".ToCharArray()).ToLower())
        {
            case "key":
                d.Key = row[1].ToString().TrimStart(' ');
                break;
            case "substance":
                d.Substance = row[1].ToString().TrimStart(' ');
                break;
            case "region":
                d.Region = row[1].ToString().TrimStart(' ');
                break;
            case "area":
                d.Area = row[1].ToString().TrimStart(' ');
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    });


    return d;
}

public class DATA{

    public string Key {get;set;}
    public string Substance {get;set;}
    public string Region {get;set;}
    public string Area {get;set;}
    public DATA(){}
}
```